# YII getFlashes() not deleting?

Tags: yii

Before jumping in with an answer, please make sure you understand my scenario.

1. I have ajax calls that CREATE flashes.
2. I have other ajax calls that FETCH the flashes as JSON.

What is currently happening: I click a button which creates the flash. After which I run a ajax call that executes:

```
public function actionGetAllFlashesAsJSON() {
   $flashMessages = Yii::app()->user->getFlashes(true);
   $returnResult = array();
   foreach ($flashMessages as $key => $value) {
     $newItem = array();
     $newItem['message']  = $value;
     $newItem['kind']     = $key;
     $returnResult[]= $newItem;  
   }
   print json_encode($returnResult);
   die();
}
```

My problem is, when I execute this function twice in a row, it still keeps returning the flashes. However, if I refresh the site, it shows the error, and then if I press refresh again, it's gone. My theory is that page refresh is causing some other kind of deletion of messages... but what? And how can I force the deletion of these messages after I receive the message in the above code?

More background info: I am using the flashes as ERROR messages, but i want them to appear at the top of my site AS THEY ARE CREATED. Flashes might get created via Ajax, so I have javascript running to check for new messages, and display them, but my problem is it shows the messages several times, because they are not getting deleted after calling getFlashes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The flash messages are controlled by *SESSION* variables, which Yii destroys when the page is loaded (probably somewhere quite deep in the framework). You will have to manually destroy all the previous flash messages at the start of the ajax request

You can use: **getFlashes()** to get all the existing flash messages

For the other flash message methods have a look at the [CWebUser docs here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebUser)

Comment: Nevermind, my problem was Javascript related. It DOES delete them.... not sure if I should delete this post?

Comment: You could delete them like a normal session (destroy). Your call, delete this post if you want :)